# Smallest lengths for three-column newsfeed (like google+)?

Tags: algorithm

I am implementing a newsfeed program, similar to [Google+](https://plus.google.com/).

The problem can be abstracted as follows:

Given a list of blocks (different heights but same widths as width of a column), how do we arrange the texts in three columns to make the total length of the page smallest?

Note that blocks cannot overlap, and blocks do not follow any order.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This problem is known as [Multi-Way Number Partitioning](https://www.aaai.org/ocs/index.php/IJCAI/IJCAI-09/paper/viewFile/625/705).

> The number partitioning problem is to divide a given set of integers
>   into a collection of subsets, so that the sum of the numbers in each
>   subset are as nearly equal as possible. While a very efficient
>   algorithm exists for optimal two-way partitioning, it is not nearly as
>   effective for multi-way partitioning.

While it's NP-hard, you may find the heuristics and algorithms in the linked article efficient enough for practical purposes.